# How to clean/reinitialize Keras resources/network? How to restart training from scratch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resources, out-of-memory

I am training the same network against the same sizes of data but with different augmentation in order to find better augmentation policies.

Unfortunately, after a lot of iterations, I am getting out of memory error.

It looks like resorces are not freed on cycles.

I tried to assign `None` to model then call `gc.collect()` -- this didn't helped.

Also I tried to call `backend.clearsession()` -- this also didn't helped.

Is there any conventional method to restart training from scratch in Keras?